# Need to find count of shipment id which corresponds to certain set of order id in sql table but query is buggy

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have sales_order table

```
entity_id state    created_at
1         success  2020-05-01
2         fail     2020-05-01
3         success  2020-05-01
4         success  2020-05-01
5         process  2020-05-01
6         process  2020-05-01
7         process  2020-05-01
8         fail     2020-05-01
9         fail     2020-05-01
```

And a sales_shipment table

```
entity_id order_id   
1         1
2         1
3         2
4         2
5         3
6         4
7         4
8         4
9         5
10        6
11        6
12        6
13        6
14        7
15        7
16        8
17        9
18        9
19        9
20        9
```

I wanted to find out what is the count of entity_id from sales_shipment table which corresponds to success and process state orders from sales_order table

Expected output

```
Count
13
```

When I run the following query I am not getting the desired output

```
select `entity_id` as tem, count(*) as cntsid  
from `sales_order` a 
inner join `sales_shipment` b on a.`entity_id`= b.`order_id`
where (`state` = 'success' or  `state` = 'process')  
group by tem
```

Instead I am getting

```
Column 'entity_id' in field list is ambiguous
```

Please help with this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepend `entity_id` with the table name or alias in the first line, in this case I added `a.`. Otherwise the engine doesn't know which one to use (there are two `entity_id` columns in the query).

Your query should look like:

```
select a.`entity_id` as tem, count(*) as cntsid  
from `sales_order` a 
inner join `sales_shipment` b on a.`entity_id`= b.`order_id`
where (b.`state` = 'success' or b.`state` = 'process')  
group by tem
```